# Is there an R build tool like Maven?

Tags: r

Is there an R build tool (like Maven or Gradle for Java) to get the dependencies and package an R project?

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies, but you might look at the 'checkpoint' package.  You give it a date, and it'll find all the R packages current as of that date that are required by any R project or collection of files in a directory, and install them. You call the checkpoint function at the beginning of an R script (or as a separate script) and it'll install all package dependencies for the whole project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/)** package is what you're looking for.

It bypasses R's native packages and allows you to build and deploy a bundle of packages and dependencies.

However, it does not do Maven-style dynamic dependency resolution; you need to specify a list of packages that you believe will work together, then the bundle is installed/deployed as a single unit.